# to generate start I2C

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to interface [TMP102 Temperature sensor](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf) with stm32f4 board through I2C protocol. It looks that device is not communicating with board. I feel I'm going wrong in clock initialization and slave address.

This is where.. in starting only I'm getting stuck... please tell us where I'm going wrong?

```
while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2Cx, I2C_FLAG_BUSY))
     {
  if((I2CTimeout--) == 0) return I2C_TIMEOUT_UserCallback();}
//I'm getting stuck here


 I2C_GenerateSTART(I2Cx, ENABLE);
I2CTimeout = I2C_Open_FLAG_TIMEOUT;
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT))
{if((I2CTimeout--) == 0) return I2C_TIMEOUT_UserCallback();}
//I'm getting stuck here
```

Comment: Checking if two pieces of HW communicate with each other is a job for an oscilloscope…

Comment: What is the slave address you're sending?

Comment: 7+1bit slave address.. 0x90

Comment: So can you please tell where am I going wrong?